# Overlaying multiple geom_tile plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

First question from me, hope it's phrased correctly. I couldn't find anything on this so I'll bite the bullet.

I'd like to create a `geom_tile` plot in which for each combination of `x` and `y`, I have 5 variables for the `z` that all sum to one. I'd like the colour of the square for each `x-y` combination to reflect which `z` number is largest. For example, imagine I have 5 `z` variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`. If `a=1` and `b=c=d=e=0`, the square would be blue, if `b=1` and `a=c=d=e=0` it would be red, etc. If `a=b=0.5` and the others are zero, it would be an interpolated colour (i.e. purple). Perhaps even better, a crosshatch of red and blue, but I don't know if that is possible in `ggplot`.

I am not sure how best to go ahead. I thought about plotting 5 `geom_tile` plots on top of each other, where each one is a different colour and the alpha is scaled by e.g. the value of a (so the cell is transparent when `a = 0` and strongly coloured when `a = 1`). There might also be a way to do it using  colour ramps, but I drew a blank there too.

If anyone can see how to do this off the top of their head, I'd be much obliged. Here's a dataset of random numbers in the same format as my actual data.

```
rand <- matrix(runif(50*50*5), ncol=5, nrow=50*50)
rand <- rand / apply(rand, 1, sum) # Make sure the numbers sum to one in each row
d <- data.frame(a = rand[,1],
                b = rand[,2],
                c = rand[,3],
                d = rand[,4],
                e = rand[,5],
                expand.grid(x = 1:50, y = 1:50))
```

Update: By using the first answer from sebastian-c and my own dataset, I was able to make this figure. I obtained the colours using the function brewer.pal(5,"Spectral") in the package RColorBrewer. Needs a custom legend, but otherwise I am pretty happy with it. The solid colours show pure "Evolutionarily stable strategies" (ESS; i.e. strategies that cannot be beaten by a mutant strategy). Areas of overlapping colours show mixed ESS, in which the equilibrium is a stable balance of two or more strategies.

[image: Overlapped geom_tile plots ESS]

Comment: So let's say you have four colours: red, blue, green and purple. How do you tell apart a combination of red and blue from purple?

Comment: @sebastian-c, I agree this is one major problem with this approach: One must project a 5-dimensional vector onto 3d color space. Also, continuous 3d color spaces do not have good perceptual qualities. Such a figure might just look muddled or chaotic (depending on the data...)

Comment: @bdemarest - For this example dataset, you're totally right. But in the actual data there are large blocks of solid color, with zones of overlap between them, so it'll be clear what's going on. I am just not sure how to link to my data on this site, and the code to reproduce it takes a couple of hours to run, so I figured it'd be fine to use random numbers for proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of simplifying your example a bit down to 3 columns. Honestly, I don't think this works well with any more than 2, but here's how I've gone about it.  I've also abused alpha channels so if you lay down the tiles in a different order, the colours change. This should hopefully work as a starting point for someone else. First, we'll generate data:

```
set.seed(100)

rand <- matrix(runif(100*3), ncol=3, nrow=100)
rand <- rand / apply(rand, 1, sum) # Make sure the numbers sum to one in each row
d <- data.frame(a = rand[,1],
                b = rand[,2],
                c = rand[,3],
                expand.grid(x=1:10, y=1:10))
```

Now for the plot:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  theme_bw() + #For a clearer background
  geom_tile(alpha=d$a, fill="red")+
  geom_tile(alpha=d$b, fill="blue")+
  geom_tile(alpha=d$c, fill="green")+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

[image]

I was thinking about, for 3 columns, using amounts of red, green and blue, but this doesn't work for anything greater than 3 columns.

EDIT: A specific solution for up to 3 columns (I mixed the blue and green up):

```
d2 <- data.frame(col=rgb(rand), expand.grid(x=1:10, y=1:10))

ggplot(d2, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=col))+
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

You could do this with 2 colours if you set one of red, green or blue to 0.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, many thanks for your help (and sorry for screwing up the matrix of random numbers - now fixed). I like the look of your first solution, but running it gives me the error "Error: When _setting_ aesthetics, they may only take one value. Problems: alpha". Also, in my actual data, most squares have at least 3 zeroes, so usually there will be only one or two colours overlapping and it won't look as uninterpretable as in the random number example.

Comment: @lukeholman Are you placing it within an `aes` call? I did not. Are you using the latest ggplot2 (0.9.3)?

Comment: That fixed it! I guess something pretty fundamental was changed in the last update. Thanks again for the help, I will play around with the figure and post back when I have something useful.